# Arduino bootloader sequence

Tags: arduino

I have put together a [Bareduino](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:20015) which is an [ATmega328](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328) on a breadboard. I have a transceiver chip ([MAX233](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1798)) connected to it and to my serial port adapter on my laptop. I haven't been able to upload any [sketches](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) yet. What is the bootloader sequence? Does the Arduiono send out a character first or does the IDE? What is it looking for?

I have a manual reset button. The ATmega328 comes with a bootloader and a program already in it to blink an LED on D13 (chip pin 19). The LED is blinking on and off at one second intervals so it appears to be running. I have ordered an [FTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) board, but I scrounged up a MAX233 and thought I would give it a try. Sorry, not a coding question, but I am interested in learning about the bootloader sequence.

Comment: IIRC, the IDE sends/sets DTR, this reboots the board. the bootloader waits for a few seconds for a sketch, else runs the current sketch. The logical code for it is pretty simple. Just read it :)

Answer (score 3):

On bootlup, the Arduino waits for a signal from the IDE, if it doesn't get one, it runs the local program. Are you getting timeouts? Are you selecting the right com port and board type? depending on the boot loader installed on your chip, try duemilanove or uno. do you have the capacitor for auto reset installed?

see http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Embedded-Arduino-building-an-Arduino-into-a-p/

Comment: I added the capacitor for auto reset from the serial ports DTR pin though the MAX233. This works great. Now it uploads everytime. I also turned on verbose upload mode so I can see whats going on. I had to hand-edit the preferences.txt file to set that.